Unable to set Global Header in Swagger-UI Spring-Boot
I am configuring Swagger UI for my spring boot application and the swagger is up and running fine. Now I need to setup a global header in swagger for all the APIs, made all the changes as given below but the header is not showing up in Swagger. I am having java 17 and spring boot version is 3.1.11. Tried different solutions found online but nothing fixed the issue, any help would be greatly appreciated.
pom.xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>springfox-oas</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

SwaggerConfig.java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig {

    public List<RequestParameter> customRequestHeader(){
        
          RequestParameter requestParameter = new RequestParameterBuilder()
          .in(ParameterType.HEADER) 
          .name("Custom_Header")
          .required(true) .query(param->param
          .model(model->model.scalarModel(ScalarType.STRING))).build(); 
          return  List.of(requestParameter);
        
    }

        @Bean
        public Docket docket() {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .globalRequestParameters(customRequestHeader())
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
        }
}

Spring boot starter class has the below annotations
@SpringBootApplication
@CrossOrigin
@EnableCaching
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebMvc
@OpenAPIDefinition(servers = {@Server(url = "/", description = "Default Server URL")})
@EnableConfigurationProperties

